# md-slider is not working with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to get data on slider with ng-repeat on md-slider

I am also getting gaps for slider If I used with ng-repeat and unable to see the values top on it.

```js
$scope.data =  [
{
    id: 1,
    value: "1"
},
{
    id: 2,
    value: "2"
},
{
    id: 3,
    value: "3"
}
  ]
console.log($scope.data);
  $scope.clicked = function (id) {

      alert(id);
  };
```

```html
<md-slider-container>
      <md-slider flex ng-model="value" ng-repeat="aa in data" aria-
       label="blue" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary">
            {{aa.value}}
       </md-slider>
       <md-input-container>
            <input flex type="number" ng-model="value" aria-label="blue" 
               aria-controls="blue-slider">
        </md-input-container>
    </md-slider-container>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click=clicked(value)>Get 
    Value</md-button>
```

[image]

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: @Ruhul Amin  no error.If i give directly min and max values it is working fine,I am facing problem with ng-repeat.

Comment: see my answer, you used wrong markup for slider.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong markup. Try this:

```
 <md-content>
      <md-slider-container ng-repeat="aa in data">
      <span>{{aa.value }}</span>
      <md-slider flex ng-model="color.green" min="0" max="255" aria-label="green" id="green-slider" class="md-accent">
      </md-slider>
      <md-input-container>
        <input flex type="number" ng-model="color.green" aria-label="green" aria-controls="green-slider">
      </md-input-container>
    </md-slider-container>


  </md-content>
```